# Discord.py I want to have ,open as the command for this but it gives an error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on creating a economy bot on Discord but whenever my command is ,create it works fine but when I try change the commands name to ,open it gives me this error

The Error:

```
/home/runner/w/main.py:13: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
  with open('user_accounts.json', 'w') as f:
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2024-02-20 23:51:22 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command open
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/w/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/w/main.py", line 33, in open
    save_accounts()
  File "/home/runner/w/main.py", line 13, in save_accounts
    with open('user_accounts.json', 'w') as f:
AttributeError: __enter__

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/w/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/w/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/runner/w/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: __enter__
```

My Code:

```
def save_accounts():
    with open('user_accounts.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(user_accounts, f, indent=4)

try:
    with open('user_accounts.json', 'r') as f:
        user_accounts = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    user_accounts = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} is online')

@bot.command()
async def open(ctx):
    user_id = str(ctx.author.id)
    if user_id not in user_accounts:
        user_accounts[user_id] = {'balance': 15}
        await ctx.send('Account created successfully!')
        save_accounts()
    else:
        await ctx.send('You already have an account.')
```

I've tried making the command name ,create and it works fine but I need it to be ,open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `with` keyword, you are triggering the `__enter__` method.

The error; coroutine was never awaited, tells us that there is an asynchronous function that was ran without the `await` keyword.

But where is the problem in the code?

Well, you have actually reassigned the built-in open function as your command callback. And is not awaited in `with open()`, throwing the error. To fix this while maintaining the command name, we can assign the name of the command in the decorator.

```
@bot.command(name="open")
async def open_command(ctx):
    ...
```

To avoid this error, make sure that you are not redefining any built-in functions like `open`.

Documentation: [@bot.command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command)